# waiting on data that is imported

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am working on a react app using Node.js.

I need to simplify my component so I took out the fetch calls and put them into their own file (dataDown.js) and then imported them into the file.

When I try to update the state the data has downloaded yet.
So how should I down get the data from external file making the fetch call.
downdata is an object with two arrays in it

```
`fetch(urlRecent).then((response) => {

response
  .json()
  .then((data) => {
    dataDown.recent = data
  })
})
fetch(urlAllTime).then((response) => {

  response
    .json()
    .then((data) => {
      dataDown.alltime = data
    })
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err)
})

export default dataDown`
```

then i import it

> import dataDown from '../../data/downData'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

Make a function out of the hole fetch-Call, make it return the dataDown Object and import the function.

That way you can rely on the data you are getting.